# Returning values from recusive function

Tags: python, recursion, return

This Code prints all Paths in a Graph from startNode to destinationNode.
I copied it from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/ and modified it slightly. The Code works perfectly fine, but i need the paths to be returned instead of printed, but don't get how to do that.
If I add return to `printAllPathsUtil(i, d, unvisited, path)` it only returns one of the paths.

I am not that good at recursion and don't know what to do now.

```
async def getAllPathsUtil(s, d, unvisited, path): 
    unvisited.append(s)
    path.append(s) 
    if s == d: 
        path
    else: 
        for i in (await children(s)):
            if not(i in unvisited):
                await getAllPathsUtil(i, d, unvisited, path)
    path.pop() 
    unvisited.remove(s)

async def printAllPaths(startNode, destinationNode):
    all_paths = await getAllPathsUtil(startNode, destinationNode, [], [])
    print(all_paths)
```

Comment: _"I am not that good at recursion and don't know what to do now"_ you won't learn recursion by copying random code online and hacking at it until you get some sort of output. See [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). You learn recursion by studying it and understanding how it works. With a name like @asdasdasd I guess you're in a bit of a rush.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your recursive algorithm, than using `yield` might be the simplest option.

```py
def graph_paths(s, d, visited, path): 
    visited.append(s)
    path.append(s) 
    if s == d: 
        yield path
    else: 
        for i in children(s):
            if i not in visited:
                yield from graph_paths(i, d, visited, path)

    path.pop() 
    visited.remove(s)

def print_graph_paths(start_node, dest_node):
  for path in graph_paths(start_node, dest_node, [], []):
    print(path)
```

But as a better approach I recommend to replace a recursion calls by the stack, it will neutralize the maximum recursion depth problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Replacing the recursion call sounds great. Can you give me an example how it would work in this case?
I just tried the code. I declared both functions as async, I didn't knew that it would be a problem thus i didn't mention it. Is there an easy fix for the ```'yield from' inside async function``` error?

Comment: Starting from `python 3.6` there are async generators and `yield` works same as usual.

Regarding the algorithm update, I'm using 

```
            Q = [(start, [start])]
            while Q:
                node, path = Q.pop()
                if not discovery[node]:
                    discovery[node] = 1

                    for n in graph[node]:
                        if n == start:
                            available.append(path + [n])
                        elif not discovery[n]:
                            Q.append((n, path + [n]))
```

Comment: @asdasdasd The recursive call in this case is safe in practical cases. The tree would have to be over 500 descendants deep before the stack would overflow. If this is an issue for you, search how to use a stack for traversing trees.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
I guess the maximum depth would be way below 100, but it's nice to know a way to solve it